# Oracle sql convert char format to date (to_date) with AM

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a requirement of converting char '2019/01/06 00:00:00' to date format with HH:MI:SS AM.
ex: '2019/01/06 00:00:00' -> 1/6/2019 12:00:00 AM

i have tried below,

```
to_date(to_char(to_date(substr('2019/01/06 00:00:00',1,10),'YYYY/MM/DD'),'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM'),'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM')
```

i got the result as 1/6/2019 (*but can see timestamp with AM)

whereas the same with +1/24 (one hour addition), give timestamp

```
to_date(to_char(to_date(substr('2019/01/06 00:00:00',1,10),'YYYY/MM/DD'),'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM'),'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM')+1/24
```

-> 1/6/2019 1:00:00 AM (shows timestamp)

Can you please let know how can i get timestamp for the above where i'm not getting it

Answer (score 4):

In the code you posted, you are doing a number of weird things; for example, the last function call is to `to_date`, which produces a date, not a string. When that is printed to the screen, the conversion to string is controlled by your session's `nls_date_format` setting, not by anything you do in the code.

I also don't believe you that you get the time-of-day component in one case but not in the other. It would be very interesting to see how that is possible (namely, to see what `nls_date_format` value can lead to that).

In any case - the only correct way to take a string that represents date in one format, and output the same date also as a string, but in a different format, is to apply `to_date` with the proper format on the input string, and then apply `to_char` to the result with the desired format model.

You seem to be able to do the first part, but not the second. In order to get month and day-of-the-month in the format `1` (rather than `01`), for example, you must use the `fm` format model modifier. But this will also cause hours, minutes and seconds to be shown in the same format, which you don't want. So you must use `fm` a second time, as shown below. Note that `fm` is a **switch** - if you use it once, it turns out "minimal formatting"; if you use it again, it turns it off; etc.

So:

```
select to_char(to_date('2019/01/06 00:00:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'),
              'fmmm/dd/yyyy fmhh:mi:ss AM') as result
from   dual;

RESULT              
--------------------
1/6/2019 12:00:00 AM
```

Or, if you must show many dates (perhaps in a report) using the desired format model, you can change your `nls_date_format` like so:

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'fmmm/dd/yyyy fmhh:mi:ss AM'
```

Then you won't need to apply `to_char` explicitly; but if your inputs are still strings, you must still call `to_date` on them with the proper format model (that is, the *existing* format, in which those strings are written).

Answer (score 0):

Unlike other databases, Oracle stores a time along with the date in the `date` data type.  However, you cannot see it generally when it is printed out.

One way to see the timestamp is to convert the value to `timestamp`.  Here is a small [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b566548ae00e56dd316b11fcc3f4d7a0) that illustrates this.

Comment: What do you mean by "you cannot see it generally when it is printed out"? That is utter nonsense. Whether the time portion is visible is controlled by the format model used - either explicitly by the programmer, or implicitly (`nls_date_format`). Saying that the format model "generally does not include the time component" makes no sense, what do you mean by that?

Comment: @mathguy the OP did tag SQL Developer, and if I remember correctly its default setting is `'DD-MON-RR'`.

Comment: If the OP had tagged PL/SQL Developer it would make more sense, as it suppresses the time component when it's '00:00:00'.